# creating composite controls in firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Delphi XE-6

I am trying to create my own custom Firemonkey control derived from TGroupBox, where I create a TGridPanelLayout Control on the groupbox.

```
constructor TMyRadioGroup.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  FLayout:= TGridPanelLayout.Create(self);
  FLayout.Parent:= self;
end;
```

How do I prevent the user from being able to select and /or delete the TGridPanelLayout control? At design time, I only want my parent control (derived from TGroupbox) to be select-able and delete-able from the form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the `Stored` property to `false` for each child control you do not want selectable at design time. For example the following code creates a panel with two child controls, a `TEdit` and a `TButton`.

```
unit PanelCombo;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, FMX.Types, FMX.Controls,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.Edit;

type
  TPanelCombo = class(TPanel)
  private
    { Private declarations }
    edit1: TEdit;
    button1: TButton;
  protected
    { Protected declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
     constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
     destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    { Published declarations }
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Samples', [TPanelCombo]);
end;

constructor TPanelCombo.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  edit1:= TEdit.create(self);
  edit1.parent:= self;
  edit1.align:= TAlignLayout.Top;
  edit1.stored:= false;

  button1:= TButton.create(self);
  button1.parent:= self;
  button1.align:= TAlignLayout.bottom;
  button1.stored:= false;
end;

destructor TPanelCombo.Destroy;
begin
  inherited;
  edit1.Free;
  button1.Free;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Ahhhhhhh - Thank You!